# Implementing K-Medoids in numpy: the medoids selection step

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization, k-means

As the author of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8637475/numpy-vectorize-sum-of-distances-to-a-set-of-points) I'm trying to implement [K-Medoids](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-medoids) using numpy. However I'm more interested in how to implement the medoids-individuation step (second step in [[2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-medoids)]), consisting in selecting, cluster by cluster, the sample that minimizes the sum of the distances from the other samples belonging to the same cluster. 
Let assume we have the same structures described in [[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8637475/numpy-vectorize-sum-of-distances-to-a-set-of-points)]:

```
# Number of samples
n_samples = 5
# Distance square matrix
D = np.array([[ 0.,  3.04959014,  4.74341649,  3.72424489,  6.70298441],
              [ 3.04959014,  0.        ,  5.38516481,  4.52216762,  6.16846821],
              [ 4.74341649,  5.38516481,  0.        ,  1.02469508,  8.23711114],
              [ 3.72424489,  4.52216762,  1.02469508,  0.        ,  7.69025357],
              [ 6.70298441,  6.16846821,  8.23711114,  7.69025357,  0.        ]])
# Medoids
medoids = np.array([0, 3])
# Cluster membership array
cl = np.array([0, 0, 1, 1, 0])
```

I can't implement it using numpy ... can someone help me?

[EDIT]
my current best solution is:

```
for c in range(number_of_clusters):
    ind = np.where(cl == c)[0]
    m = np.argmin(D[np.ix_(ind, ind)].sum(axis=0))
    medoids[c] = ind[m]
```